# create instances of classes in loop

Tags: c#

I have folder that contains some classes with the same behavior (they contain one Run function that get int param and all inherit from the same class).
I need to create in loop instance from these classes and execute their function with the parameter.

That is what I started-

```
f = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "ConsoleApplication3.JJJ");
A[] a = new A[f.Count()];
for (int i = 0; i < a.Count(); a[i]=new A(), i++);
for (int i = 0; i < a.Count(); i++)
{
   // (a[i] as f[i].GetType()).Run(0);
}
```

I don’t know how to continue, and if it's good at all…

Answer (score 2):

you are searching for activator class
see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;

class DynamicInstanceList
{
    private static string instanceSpec = "System.EventArgs;System.Random;" +
        "System.Exception;System.Object;System.Version";

    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] instances = instanceSpec.Split(';');
        Array instlist = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), instances.Length);
        object item;
        for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
        {
            // create the object from the specification string
            Console.WriteLine("Creating instance of: {0}", instances[i]);
            item = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(instances[i]));
            instlist.SetValue(item, i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nObjects and their default values:\n");
        foreach (object o in instlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type:     {0}\nValue:    {1}\nHashCode: {2}\n",
                o.GetType().FullName, o.ToString(), o.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}

// This program will display output similar to the following: 
// 
// Creating instance of: System.EventArgs 
// Creating instance of: System.Random 
// Creating instance of: System.Exception 
// Creating instance of: System.Object 
// Creating instance of: System.Version 
// 
// Objects and their default values: 
// 
// Type:     System.EventArgs 
// Value:    System.EventArgs 
// HashCode: 46104728 
// 
// Type:     System.Random 
// Value:    System.Random 
// HashCode: 12289376 
// 
// Type:     System.Exception 
// Value:    System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown. 
// HashCode: 55530882 
// 
// Type:     System.Object 
// Value:    System.Object 
// HashCode: 30015890 
// 
// Type:     System.Version 
// Value:    0.0 
// HashCode: 1048575
```